# trigger an procedure from record selection of a subform

Tags: vba, ms-access

I have a subform called MacroAttivitàSub. It  has a worksheet layout. The subform recordsource is a query result. On its side I have a text box naled 'text520' which must show the value of the field 'descrizione' of the subform when the user select the desired record row. In the form property tab there is no OnClick event. See image link please.
[form with no OnClick event](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Wgb1e.png)
There are only 'Enter' and 'Exit'. Why? I tried unsuccesfully this code behind its main form:

```
Sub MacroAttivitàSub_OnClick()
    Text520.Value = Me!MacroAttivitàSub.Form!descrizione.Value
End Sub
```

What am I missing?

Answer (score 0):

The "Form" actually does have a On-Click event. [image]

However for what it sounds like you are trying to do I would add the On-Click Event at the detail level and not the form level. That way you can capture the specific record you are clicking on:
[image]

Comment: Hi Anthony, my subform doesn't have OnClick event (see image attached in my post). Have you the idea of why?

Comment: It does... but in order to see it... it would be simpler if you opened up the subform itself. You may be thinking of it as still being a query... and it is. But the second you drop a query into a form it actually creates another form. Judging from your image look in your Forms Object List for a form called "query query...". You should then see what I was talking about when you open this form up separately.

Answer (score 0):

If you want an event that triggers every time the form loads a new record use `OnCurrent`.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to react to events in the subform, you must create an actual form that you insert as subform, instead of the query that you currently have.

A **subform control** (which you have selected in your screenshot) only has `OnEnter` and `OnExit` events. This is by design.

And a query inside a subform control has no events at all (same as a "regular" query).

Comment: The subform displayed in the image was placed there by dragging the form from the left menu that shows all the forms. Is there a different way?

Comment: @AlessioCazzaniga: The point is: you dragged a query, not a form. To use events, you must create a new form, based on the query, probably with Default View = Datasheet. Then drag this new form into the main form.

Comment: believe me I dragged a form! I can even make you a video showing you this :) .. Anyway I dragged a form and set as recordsource the query. Probably for access when setting a query as recordsource of a form it considers it a query..

Comment: You probably set the query as `SourceObject` of the subform control, not as `RecordSource` of the form. @AlessioCazzaniga

Answer (score 0):

You don't have to write code for this.

First "`create an unbound text box`" on the main form, then change the control source property of the text box from data tab in properties window to:

```
[SubForm_Name].[Form]![Control_Name_in_SubForm_to_gather_data]
```